# How to use Python to append dictionary based on csv dataset

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a code based on a csv dataset of the number of passengers arriving at stations around multiple cities. My code needs to output the city with the most numbers of passengers arriving by finding the sum of arrivals across all stations in that city and output that number.
Currently my code outputs nothing for the city with most arrivals and -1 for the number of arrivals in that city.
I'm not sure what my error is. Please help!
This is my code:

```
cities = {}
is_first_line = True
for row in open("Passengers_Analysis.csv"):
  if is_first_line:
    is_first_line = False
  else:
    values = row.split(",")
    city = values[3]
    if city not in cities:
      cities[city] = []
    cities[city].append(city)
passengers = {}
for key in passengers:
  passengers+=int(values[6]) 
max_city = ""
max_passengers = -1
for key in passengers:
  if passengers[key] > max_passengers:
    max_passengers = passengers[key]
    max_city = key
print("The most popular city:", max_city)
print("The number of passengers in the scheduled period:", max_passengers)
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample line from your file?

Comment: Also post how your input data looks like, without it we cannot really say anything about your problem.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at your code, this is exactly the behaviour the code should produce.
In line 12 you declare an empty dictionary called "passengers".
In the lines 13 and 17 you create loops, which cycle over all elements in this dictionary. As the dictionary is empty, none of the loops gets executed and your max_city and max_passengers remain on their initial values.

At least the first loop is probably meant to run on your input data.

I recommend to clarify the flow of your programm first and then try to fix the loops.
And anyway, please provide a minimal, reproducible example.